# how to add multiple dialogs in angular7 such that it return to its previous dialog and also reflecting data changes in the parent component

Tags: angular7

When a click on cancel (using confirm()) its not going back to previous dialog but to the parent component.

Tried creating a html, instead of confirm() , but still it not working as it is going to parent component instead of previous dialog.

Comment: A bit more context may make it possible to help more. Are we talking about browser built in dialogs, `confirm` etc. Have you created any custom dialog implementations, or using any 3rd party libraries for creating dialogs?

Comment: Tried with built in dialog- confirm. Then created a custom dialog implementation, since couldn't resolve the issue had to revert back again to built in.